# regex not working for password

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to use this regex

```
.*[!@#$%^&*()].*[0-9]|[0-9].*[!@#$%^&*()].*
```

to make my passwords have at least 1 special character and 1 number (which it does). But I am trying to also have it take passwords like `mike1@` .

How can I modify it so it takes letters like that as well?

Comment: This is a very bad use of regular expressions.  Just because you have regular expressions does not mean you should use them here.  A simple character by character scan would be simpler and work just as well.

Comment: I'd probably not use a regex like that but analyze each character and collect a number of properties (like contains number, lower case char, upper case char, special char, etc.) and check the password for those properties. Makes it easier to understand, more flexible and easier to tell the user what's wrong with the password.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its better to do this using `lookaheads`.

```
^(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).*$
```

The problem with your approach is you will have to cover all possible combinations where in a letter comes first,or a number comes first.Using `lookahead` which are `0 width assertions` are just a type of check,we can fail the regex if it does not have even a single `special character` or `number` or `letter`.

`(?=.*[a-zA-Z])`

```
 ^^   ^^^^^^^
```

The lookahead simply states that for this regex to pass there should be at least one `letter` somewhere.

EDIT:

```
^(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()])(?=.*[0-9]).*$
```

Use this if letter constraint is not present.

Comment: Just for others that stumble over this regex, could you add an explanation as well (e.g. "matches if the first position is followed by ...").

Comment: i tried this one and it works for most of the passwords which is fine by me. but it still has to take 1! and !1 as password , which it does now  i think im gonna take a different approach rather then a regex lol , it giving me a headache

Comment: @user3225981 but you said there has to be at least a letter?

Comment: aaahhh!!! it works!! thank you so much!!  now i have to analyze it so i can understand it lol. thanks so much